# TYPO3 cache behaviour with updated models

Tags: caching, typo3, filereference, fal

I have this weird behaviour from Typo3 6.2 LTS.
In my extension I have a Model with a FileReference Property. This property has a `vaule != 0`. This value does exist in `sys_file_reference` table.

Not the weird magic happens. If I try to access this file, I do only get a `null`value instead of a FileReference- / FileObject.

We already cleared our cache (server and browser) but nothing. It's still `null`.

I appreciate every kind of help!

Greetz, Paddaels

Comment: After changed extension model file, you need to once extension is **uninstall / install** and clear all cache in install tools.

Comment: Okay, i uninstalled and installed the extension. During this process, I did clear all cache... and it's still not weorking :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I remember it was always hard to make a 1:1 relation from a domain model to a FileReference. I suggest you to use existing patterns and work with a ObjectStorage for that purpose.

You can copy the neccessary TCA from the existing tca of the tt_content table (field image for example). The Property annotation should look like:

```
/**
 * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage<\Vendor\Extension\Domain\Model\FileReference>
 * @lazy
 * @cascade remove
 */
 protected $propName;
```

Of course you have to create the FileReference Model in your own namespace. But you can extend the Extbase basemodel, so you dont have to write any methods.

To map your model to the sys_file_reference table you have to add some typoscript.

For that purpose create a ext_typoscript_setup.txt in your extensions folder and insert the following code (adjust namespace and modelname)

```
config.tx_extbase.persistence.classes {
    Vendor\Extension\Domain\Model\FileReference.mapping {
        tableName = sys_file_reference
    }
}
```

After clearing the caches in the install tool (and making database migrations of course) it should work.

**Explanations:**

**@lazy:** Typo3 wont fetch all references at once, only if the property is accessed.

**@cascade remove:** Extbase will delete all sys_file_reference records related to your domain model once the model is deleted.

Comment: So, you are trying to tell me that I should use a 1:n relation instead of a 1:1?

Comment: Hm... I've read some articles and I came across something interesting.

`array(
   'maxitems' => 6,
   'foreign_match_fields' => array(
    'fieldname' => 'image',
    'tablenames' => 'tx_ext_domain_model_person',
    'table_local' => 'sys_file',
   ),
  ),`
That's a snippet I could got from http://www.typo3tiger.de/blog/post/extbase-fal-filereference-im-controller-erzeugen.html

In my TCA Config File I have the following: 
`array('maxitems' => 1),`

I know, I do have a 1:1 relation instead of an 1:n relation. But shouldn't my TCA File have something similar?!